# A fixed div that takes 100% of the parent container (whose width is set as a percentage, not pixels)

Tags: html, css

How can I create a container with `position: fixed;` that would occupy 100% of its parent container? The problem is that the width of the parent container is set not in pixels, but in percentages.

In the example below, the red container should have the same width as the green container, which width must remain equals to 100%.

This is a copy of a question that I closed because of the typo in the name where I accidentally used the wrong language (this is what happens when a tired programmer types text without looking at the screen).

```css
.parent{
  width: 50%;
  border: solid green 2px;
}
.child{
  height: 200px;
  border: solid red 2px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Text text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: why you need the div to be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this solution help you?

```css
.parent{
  width: 50%;
  border: solid green 2px;
  transform: translate(0px, 50%);
}
.child{
  height: 200px;
  border: solid red 2px;
  position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Text text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: An interesting option, thank you!